# What's the proper way to use `NUMBERFMT` with `GetNumberFormatEx`?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing a locale-aware Node application for Windows, Mac, and Linux. Since JavaScript's handling of locales doesn't take into account a user's custom regional settings, I'm writing a native Node module to handle this for each platform.

I'm designing a function that takes a number to format and a precision (number of digits after the decimal) and returns a string. For example, if I pass in 1234.456 with precision 1, and my regional settings use "_" for groups and "/" for decimals, I would expect "1_234/5", using the appropriate locale info of the user's current language and region settings.

On the Windows side of things, I'm struggling to get the Windows API to give me exactly what I want. Here's the C++ function I'm writing:

```cpp
std::string FormatNumber(const double number, const int precision)
{
    std::wstringstream stream;
    stream.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
    stream.precision(precision);
    stream << number;
    std::wstring roundedNumberStr = stream.str();
    const wchar_t *numStr = roundedNumberStr.c_str();

    wchar_t wBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetNumberFormatEx(
        LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, // lpLocaleName,
        0,                        // dwFlags,
        numStr,                   // lpValue,
        NULL,                     // lpFormat,
        wBuffer,                  // lpNumberStr,
        MAX_PATH                  // cchNumber
    );

    // Return a std::string using wBuffer
}
```

This almost works perfectly, except it always tacks on 2 decimal places regardless of the precision I use (something like "1_234/00"). To fix this, I suspect I need to pass in a parameter for `lpFormat`. The Windows API documentation suggests that I only need to provide values that I want to control and leave the rest to the user's settings, so I tried something like this:

```cpp
    NUMBERFMTW format{ precision };
    GetNumberFormatEx(
        LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, // lpLocaleName,
        0,                        // dwFlags,
        numStr,                   // lpValue,
        &format,                  // lpFormat,
        wBuffer,                  // lpNumberStr,
        MAX_PATH                  // cchNumber
    );
```

But...that causes an `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error. Sadly, the documentation doesn't give me any more insight.

So how do I get this function to give me the strings I am expecting?

Comment: You need a lot more code to set *all* of the members of *format*.

Comment: First thing I'd do is to init `format`: `NUMBERFMTW format {};`

Comment: Interestingly, when switching my older codebase over to VS2019, I now get a const incompatibility warning when initializing my `NUMBERFMT` struct as a const literal! It looks like the definition of `NUMBERFMT` is `LPWSTR` instead of `LPCWSTR`. I don't trust Microsoft enough that this isn't just a holdover from old C days to not modify this... I'm going to surround the function with a `#pragma strict_gs_check(push, on)`/`#pragma strict_gs_check(pop)` directive just to be extra safe!

Answer (score 1):

The two strings in NUMBERFMT are not optional. The other members are optional in the sense that 0 is valid but 0 does not mean they get their correct locale specific values!

Call `GetLocaleInfoEx` with `LOCALE_SDECIMAL` and `LOCALE_STHOUSAND` to load the "correct" strings and `LOCALE_SGROUPING` for the grouping. MSDN tells you which locale query to use for the other members.

Answer (score 0):

Completely initialize your NUMBERFORMAT:

```
NUMBERFMTW format{NumDigits };
```

With what you have any members that aren't initialized have unspecified (and likely random) values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! My C++ is a bit rusty. Unfortunately, that doesn't eliminate the error.